# Are My Answers for This RSA Question Correct?

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key

[image: Questions]

I am very new to cryptography and so I am looking for feedback on this question on RSA. Please let me know if I have made any mistakes, Thank you!

(a).

RSA Algorithm:

-choose two primes p,q

-compute n = p * q

-compute phi = (p-1)*(q-1)

-choose e such that 1 < e < phi and gcd(e,phi) = 1 where gcd is greatest common divisor

-e is the public key

-calculate d such that d = phi * k + 1 / e for some integer k

-d is private key

-cipher text c for plain text

-m is computed as: c = m^e mod n

-plain text m for cipher text c is computed as m = c^d mod n

```
  p = 83 ; q = 89 then,

  n = 7387

  phi = 7216

  e = 193

  d = 4811

  c = 4336 => 2^193 mod 7387
```

b)

No, 11 is not a valid private key

Cipher text using 11 as private key is "2048".

Where as decrypting using d = 4811 is 2404 which is not equal to original 2

c)

private key "d = 4811" for public key 25

Comment: b) Instead of decryption find $\gcd(11,7216)$ where $7217 = 2*2*2*2*11*41$ c) show the steps? Notes 1) Please learn $\LaTeX$, 2) Include you all details. Some ways are giving link from wolfram alpha or Sagemath.

Comment: Really sorry about the layout, I will learn!

Comment: [Using MathJax / TEX on the Cryptography site](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/using-mathjax-tex-on-the-cryptography-site)

Comment: So for b) gcd(11, 7216) = 11. Therefore, gcd does not equal 1 so 11 is not a private key. Is this correct?

Comment: for a) I do not think I calculated d correctly, please confirm

Comment: (a1) The question uses "_public key_" to designate the public exponent $e$ (rather than $(n,e)$ which is what public key usually means). Thus you do not want to "choose" $e$, that choice is done. You want to choose the $p$ and $q$ to match $e$. (a2) $p$ and $q$ should be large random primes, e.g. 1024-bit, otherwise the cryptosystem won't be secure. (a3) if you insist on small $p,q$ they must expressly be made distinct (otherwise plaintext multiple of the prime won't decipher, and $\phi$ is computed differently). (b) $d=11$ is too small to be a secure valid private exponent.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=193%5E-1+mod+7216

Comment: d) I get d = 4041: ed mod(phi). Therefore, d = e^-1 mod(phi) = 25^-1 mod(7216) = 4041. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. $d=e^{-1}\bmod\operatorname{lcm}(83-1,89-1)=25^{-1}\bmod3608=433$ works just as well.